# How to get my "jumbotron" responsive?

Tags: html, css

```
.jumbotron{
  width:100%;
  height:50vh;
  background: url('longboard.jpeg');
  color:white;
}
```

I'm trying to build a "jumbotron" from scratch. Currently the html for it is just a  with nothing in it. As of right now the picture simply cuts off on the right side while my navbar scales downward. i would like the background picture to also shrink with it. How do I go about doing this?

Also whenever I add a  or anythign to the div a margin appears above my navbar which I didn't thing was connected. Sorry in advance if i broke any posting etiquette, this is my first post on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
.jumbotron {
    background: url('longboard.jpeg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
}
```

Resource - https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to set the background size to `"cover"`

```
.jumbotron {
background-image: url('longboard.jpeg');
background-size: cover;
height:50vh;
color:white;
}
```